# Uncaught TypeError: toDo is undefined ,Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs

(sending todo as toDo - i think problem is here but don,t know the solution )

todos.js file

```
import React from 'react'
 import {Todo} from './todo';
  export const Todos = (props) => {
   return (
     <div className='container'>
     <h3>Todo List</h3>
     {props.toDos.map((todo) => {
      return <Todo toDo={todo}/>;
      })}
    </div>
     )
 }
```

todo.js file

```
import React from 'react';
 export const Todo = ({toDo}) => {
   return (
    <div>
        <h4>{toDo.title}</h4>
        <p>{toDo.desc}</p>
    </div>
  )
```

}

Comment: What is the value of `props.toDos`? that is being mapped? Is the error saying the `toDo` prop is undefined in `Todo` component? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

1. `toDo is undefined`
   Make sure the `toDos` prop doesn't contain any undefined values.
2. `Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop`
   Elements in arrays in React should have keys. If your todos have an attribute that uniquely identifies them, such as `todo.id`, you can do :

```
export const Todos = (props) => {
   return (
     <div className='container'>
     <h3>Todo List</h3>
     {props.toDos.map((todo) => {
      return <Todo toDo={todo} key={todo.id}/>;
      })}
    </div>
     )
 }
```

If you don't have any `todo.id` attribute or equivalent, only if the todo
list is **never going to change its order of elements**, you can use the list index :

```
export const Todos = (props) => {
   return (
     <div className='container'>
     <h3>Todo List</h3>
     {props.toDos.map((todo, index) => {
      return <Todo toDo={todo} key={index}/>;
      })}
    </div>
     )
 }
```